# Converting a timestamp to a unix_timestamp in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, unix-timestamp

I need to convert a timestamp to a unix_timestamp in Postgres.

The timestamp being in the following format: 2019-05-09 11:40:01

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `extract(epoch from . . . )`:

```
select extract(epoch from '2019-05-09 11:40:01'::timestamp)
```